libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
I getting an issue in react native ios build is install successfully but crash it when launch it.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTRootView setReactTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107a11420'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80049b761 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff800063904 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004b0873 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bf2efc -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 266
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80049fef4 ___forwarding___ + 1459
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004a20f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   Karni Die Cuttting                  0x000000010333122a -[RCTRootView reactTag] + 330
    7   Karni Die Cuttting                  0x00000001033316a5 -[RCTRootView bundleFinishedLoading:] + 405
    8   Karni Die Cuttting                  0x000000010332fe5e -[RCTRootView initWithFrame:bridge:moduleName:initialProperties:] + 1774
    9   Karni Die Cuttting                  0x000000010333000c -[RCTRootView initWithBridge:moduleName:initialProperties:] + 172
    10  Karni Die Cuttting                  0x00000001036188a0 RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView + 144
    11  Karni Die Cuttting                  0x0000000103614ead -[RCTAppDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:moduleName:initProps:] + 125
    12  Karni Die Cuttting                  0x0000000103614603 -[RCTAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 579
    13  Karni Die Cuttting                  0x000000010302ae43 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 323
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bb6fc2 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 297
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bb8d9b -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 4253
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bbe8fd -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1241
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804ef1fc1 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8055d8f44 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 87
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804ef2b1f __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804ef2580 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 249
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804ef2968 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 813
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804ef2194 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 341
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804eff6fb __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_blo  24  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805488b08 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 865
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8055f7563 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 261
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804eff38a -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 347
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804cd1caa __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.610 + 877
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804cd065f -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 245
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff804cd1812 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 252
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bbd14f -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 672
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8054bdd31 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 353
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff8078d263f -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 406
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff807905056 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.254 + 279
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff8078e2353 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 213
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff807904d50 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 328
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b019f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b05389 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 507
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff8079309a7 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff807930881 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 188
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007ff8079309cf -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 19
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f8283 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f81c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f79c2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f20f7 __CFRunLoopRun + 919
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f197d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    46  GraphicsServices                    0x00007ff80fe9d08f GSEventRunModal + 137
    47  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bbb53d -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    48  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bbffab UIApplicationMain + 123
    49  Karni Die Cuttting                  0x000000010302b778 main + 104
    50  dyld                                0x000000010643f3e0 start_sim + 10
    51  ???                                 0x00000001116ed41f 0x0 + 4587443231
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

getting alert in main.m
Thread 1: "-[RCTRootView setReactTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107a11420"
i have try following steps

delete pods
reinstall all the pods
reinstall all the pods
remove node_modules and install again

but still getting this problem.
